# Jquery inner quotes adding a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have browsed stack over flow and have not come up with a solution that seems to fix my issue so I am resorting to asking this fine community.

```
        var feild = '<div  style="margin-top: 0.75%;" class="input-group input-group-lg fields urlInputOne">' + 
    '<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" id="basic-addon1"></span>' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="urlField" placeholder="Extra GitHub repository URL" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">' +
    '</div>';
```

In the input tag I want to add a variable to the id, how can i do this? I have tried a few different options but kept getting errors in the browser.

so i want it to be

id="urlfeild"+1 as an example.

thanks

Comment: Close the quotes, add the value, re-open the quotes.

Comment: did you try  id="urlfeild'+1+'"  ... while your single quotes is a main one .. to add js variable use  '+ vaiable_here +' and you want it inside a id double quotes so  " yourId ' + variable_here + ' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply concatenate your string and add your variable this way:

```
var yourVar = 1;
var feild = '<div  style="margin-top: 0.75%;" class="input-group input-group-lg fields urlInputOne">' + 
    '<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" id="basic-addon1"></span>' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="urlField' + yourVar + '" placeholder="Extra GitHub repository URL" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">' +
    '</div>';
```

Comment: this did it, thanks! Not sure what i missed in my own attempts but this worked